# Magento 2 Terms and Conditions store view column not showing in the grid?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, terms-and-conditions

> Admin => Stores=> Settings => Terms and Conditions => Grid

I am facing one issue with the **store view column at**  *Terms and condition* Section in Magento 2.2.0

Please find the screenshots below:

**Magento ver. 2.1.8** http://prntscr.com/h9t0nh  (working fine)

**Magento ver. 2.2.0** http://prntscr.com/h9t3or  (not showing correctly)

Could anyone please help me how to fix this issue?

Thanks